# Find the Index of a Property's Object of an Array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Here's a simplified version of the situation:

```
//"mc" and "mc2" are Movie Clip instance names
var ary:Array=[mc, mc2];
mc.timer=new Timer(1000);
mc2.timer=new Timer(1000);
for(var i=0;i<ary.length;i++){
    ary[i].timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,alarm);
}
function alarm(e:TimerEvent){
    //how do I figure out which MovieClip's timer went off, as well as that mc's index?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the target timer

```
function alarm(e:TimerEvent){
    var timer:Timer = e.target as Timer;
}
```

Find target mc

```
var ary:Array=[mc, mc2];
mc.timer=new Timer(1000);
mc2.timer=new Timer(1000);

//save the MovieClip
var dict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
dict[mc.timer] = mc;
dict[mc2.timer] = mc2;

for(var i=0;i<ary.length;i++){
    ary[i].timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,alarm);
}

function alarm(e:TimerEvent){
    var timer:Timer = e.target as Timer;

    var mc:MovieClip =  dict[timer] as MovieClip;//get the mc
}
```

Comment: And don't forget to do this: ary[i].timer.start() inside of your 'for' loop.  And if you trace mc.name in the last line of the 'alarm' function you'll see the order of firing.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out guys. This is exactly the input I needed

Answer (score 1):

Hrm, I'm sure someone can come up with something better, but off the top of my head...

The TimerEvent object passed in to the event handler method contains a reference to the Timer object (look up 'target' property). From there I suppose you could just loop though and check manually which movieclip it belongs to... though, if there are a lot of them, perhaps use a Dictionary then that maps your timers to movieclips?

Once you've gotten the movieclip reference, you can find the its parent and index it's at, and so forth.

(Normally, I wouldn't put the timer ref inside the movieclip -didn't even notice the movieclip class was dynamic.)